# Adding count of total rows through Marshmallow with @post_dump?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I need to add the quantity of rows returned in this query:

```
queryPostgres = db.text("""
            SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () as RowCount
            FROM (
                SELECT * ,
                    ( 3958.75 *
                    acos(sin(:lat1 / 57.2958) * sin( cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) +
                         cos(:lat1 / 57.2958) * cos( cast(latitude as double precision) / 57.2958) *
                         cos( cast(longitude as double precision) / 57.2958 - :lon1/57.2958)))
                    as distanceInMiles
                FROM "job" ) zc
            WHERE zc.distanceInMiles < :dst
            ORDER BY zc.distanceInMiles
            LIMIT :per_page
            OFFSET :offset
        """)

        jobs = cls.query.\
            from_statement(queryPostgres). \
            params(lat1=float(lat1),
                   lon1=float(lon1),
                   dst=int(dst),
                   per_page=int(per_page),
                   offset=int(offset))
        return jobs
```

As you can see I added the RowCount column to have  the total count of rows.

However as it is not part of my model, I wonder what should I do in Marshmallow so I could  add the number of rows(in the RowCount column)?

I thought I could do it with Marshmallow @post_dump() , however I could not figure out how to do it .

For more clarity here is my schema.

```
class JobSchema(ma.ModelSchema):

    def validate_state(state):
        """Validate one of 55 USA states"""
        if state not in states:
            raise ValidationError(INVALID_US_STATE)

    def validate_zipCode(zip):
        if not zipcodes.is_real(zip):
            raise ValidationError(INVALID_ZIP_CODE)

    @pre_load
    def get_longitude_for_zipCode_and_TimeCreated(self, data):
        """ This method will pass valids long,lat and time_created
        values to each job created during a POST request"""
        # Getting zip from the request to obtain lat&lon from DB
        result = modelZipCode.getZipCodeDetails(data['zipCode'])
        print(result)
        if result is None:
            raise ValidationError(INVALID_ZIP_CODE_2)
        schema = ZipCodeSchema(exclude=('id'))
        zip, errors = schema.dump(result)
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(INVALID_ZIP_CODE_3)
        else:
            data['longitude'] = zip['longitude']
            data['latitude'] = zip['latitude']
        data['time_created'] = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    title = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=4, max=80)])
    city = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=100)])
    state = fields.Str(required=True, validate=validate_state)
    zipCode = fields.Str(required=True, validate=validate_zipCode)
    description = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=80)])
    narrative = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    companyLogo = fields.Str(required=False, validate=[validate.Length(max=250)])
    companyName = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=5, max=250)])
    companyURL = fields.Str(required=True, validate=[validate.Length(min=4, max=100)])
    latitude = fields.Str(required=True)
    longitude = fields.Str(required=True)
    time_created = fields.DateTime()

    # We add a post_dump hook to add an envelope to responses
    @post_dump(pass_many=True)
    def wrap(self, data, many):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if len(data) >= 1:
           counter = data[0]['RowCount']

    return {
        data,
        counter
    }



    class Meta:
        model = modelJob
```

The most weird thing is that indeed my query is correctly returning the rowcount

[image]

Could some one please help me in finding out why I can not capture the rowcount key in the post_dump method ?

Comment: Are you using marshmallow-sqlalchemy? I don't see any marshmallow code in your snippet.

Comment: Yes . Just added the schema to my question.

Comment: I added the code to the @post_dump() and what I am getting is an error : wrong key   RowCount  in counter = data[0]['RowCount']. It see the correct rows coming from the DB however the RowCount rows does not appears.It looks like we can not add new rows this way.  Does anybody know what is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This need to be managed by the Marshmallow pre_dump or post_dump method.But indeed I decided to use an SQLAlchemy pagination methods as it gave me the total rows in the response.